# Can you tell me what is wrong with this and how to fix it?

Tags: c++, data-conversion

I have this code and I have been trying to make it work for hours

```
DWORD GetModuleNamePointer(LPSTR LPSTRModuleName, DWORD __DwordProcessId)
{ 
    MODULEENTRY32 lpModuleEntry = {0};
    HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, __DwordProcessId);
    if(!hSnapShot)
        return NULL;  
    lpModuleEntry.dwSize = sizeof(lpModuleEntry);
    BOOL __RunModule = Module32First( hSnapShot, &lpModuleEntry );
    while(__RunModule)
    {
        if(!strcmp(lpModuleEntry.szModule, LPSTRModuleName ) )
        {
            CloseHandle( hSnapShot );
            return (DWORD)lpModuleEntry.modBaseAddr;
        }
        __RunModule = Module32Next( hSnapShot, &lpModuleEntry );
    }
    CloseHandle( hSnapShot );
    return NULL;
}
```

I get an error when I try to compile it from this line.

> return (DWORD)lpModuleEntry.modBaseAddr;

And this is the error.

```
[Error] invalid conversion from 'BYTE* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'DWORD {aka long unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]
```

What do I do to fix this? I honestly have no clue.

Comment: Seems like the [MODULEENTRY32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684225(v=vs.85).aspx) member `modBaseAddr` is a pointer. You cannot convert that to a `DWORD`.

Comment: Please do not use `NULL` as a return for anything other than a pointer.  `NULL` should mean empty and you cannot have an empty DWORD as it has to have a value.  It makes sense for pointers as it is a away to say the pointer points to nothing.

Comment: What line of the code gives that error?

Comment: Why not just change the return type from `DWORD` to `BYTE*`, that would make a lot more sense considering the name of your function and since you are using NULL as fall-back return value?

Comment: @NathanOliver Updated the question to be clearer.
@Elijan9 Using `BYTE*` as the return value doesn't work either.

Comment: Using `BYTE*` as the return value and removing the cast would fix this. You must be doing something else wrong in that case.

Comment: Your variable should be called `ModuleEntry` not `lpModuleEntry` (it's not a pointer), and your argument should be of type `LPCSTR` (you want a pointer to const char, not writeable char).  Finally, the name `__DwordProcessID` is reserved to the implementation (contains a double underscore).   None of these are your problem, but they may all turn round and bite you later.

Comment: I've tried all of your suggestions but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: VTC as "cannot reproduce" , because the suggestion of "interjay" would fix the problem as described in the question